# Send intent-filter of application/pdf mimeType not work properly

Tags: android, intentfilter

In my app, I have an `activity` to receive send intent in **AndroidManifest.xml** like:

```
<activity android:name=".ReceiveSendIntentActivity"  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I use default file app to share pdf file, it work fine. But with [File Manager app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager) `intent-filter` not work, i can choose .apk file and share with my app, and when i receive intent in my `activity`, intent type become application/* although in my **AndroidManifest.xml** only allow application/pdf type:
[image]
This really annoy me, Anyone have solution for this issue?

Comment: @Itvu93 Have you faced problem for opening pdf files?

Comment: @FenilPatel No, The problem is intent-filter not restrict properly so [File Manager app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager) let me pick .apk file to share with my app although in my AndroidManifest.xml only allow application/pdf type.